# Can we use selenium webdriver for opera and safari browsers?

Tags: java, selenium

Mostly we use Selenium with Google chrome, Firefox and IE.
Can we use selenium for opera and safari browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, to test your script in `Opera Browser`.

For more details on safari browser and driver, visit this [page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver), As Apple's decision to drop Safari on Windows.

You can download opera driver from this [url](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases).

**Note:-** Make sure that your `opera browser version` is compatible with latest `opera driver`.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\operadriver.exe");    //provide your driver path.
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
```

Answer (score 0):

- Safari support for Windows has been withdrawn, you can run your Safari tests only on MAC.
- We can execute tests on Opera using following post -

> ```
>   System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "Path to Opera Driver");
>      WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
>      driver.get("https://google.com/");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but you've to set up binary for Opera and operadriver's not implement 'maximize' so you can't use: driver.manage().window().maximize();